# max string size vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, out-of-memory, filestream

I am need of a large string (eLines) to pass into a method of a type library I am using.

```
eLineID = sao.PutText(777, eLines)
```

I am unable to build the string without running out of memory, as I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll

I am trying to store the contents of a 500+ mb file into string. I have tried multiple ways to do this. This reads all the lines into individual strings, then attempts to build a string using [System.Text.StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) object

```
If (System.IO.File.Exists(filename)) Then
            Dim sB As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            Dim test As String
            Dim allLines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
            'Seperate into blocks
            For i = 0 To allLines.Count() Step 1
                test = allLines(i)
                If (test.IndexOf("\t") > -1) Then
                    test.Replace("\t", "")
                End If
                sB.AppendLine(test)
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("File object could not find specified file")
        End If
```

Another attempt read the whole file with the [System.IO.StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) object to one string at once:

```
eLines = read.ReadToEnd()
```

Reading line by line with StreamReader.ReadLine() is too slow to tell if ever will eventually run out of memory.

I know I have more than enough memory to do this (32 GB and running it never raises current memory usage by much more than 1 GB), so I was wondering what was causing the error and if there is any way I can override it.

Comment: Actually, you are loading the giant file into memory twice: once into `allLines ()` then line by line into the stringbuilder.  Stringbuilder will use 2 bytes per character, so thats aiming towards 1GB right there.   System memory doesnt matter, from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx): `The maximum size of a String object in memory is 2GB, or about 1 billion characters.`. Is it your library?

Comment: That would be it. I had no idea String objects had that limit. I need to be reading files even larger than this as well. I assume the software was never made to take in decks larger than a certain amount. String is what the method requires, so I assume that I am locked to this limit. I will take this into account. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: is that the only way it can be called - with a Giant String Array?  Can you do it in chunks?

Comment: The only way to call it is by passing in a single string

Comment: but can you call it by sending chunks of the source file at a time?

Comment: Yes, but I am sending one chunk in particular (defined by the 777 you see), and that cannot be split up any smaller. There are other source files that will fill up the other chunks of text. This one just happens to possibly be massive.